# Set height of ul on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Actually I have an ul which is set to a particular height using css. I'm trying to set the height of ul on clicking a div element. Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="hey">Click me</div>
<ul style="height:100px">My Height</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hey').click(function(){
        $(this).next().find('ul').css('height','10px');
    });
});
```

Did I miss anything?

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/371/)

Comment: without the html and knowing what is `this` we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ul` is the next sibling so, you need to just use .next(), no need to use .find() after that

```
$(this).next('ul').css('height', '10px');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8eLVz/)

In your case you are trying to find a `ul` element which is a descendant of the next sibling of the clicked `.hey`

Answer (score 0):

use **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** not find after next because
when we use next() then it reach to `ul`
so there is no need to find `ul` now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hey').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').css('height','10px');
    });
});
```

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/372/)**

Answer (score 0):

yes. actually **next()** will find the next element and inside that it will search for ul check it out..

```
<div class="hey">Click me</div>
<div>
  <ul style="height:100px">My Height</ul>
</div>
```

its working check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/373/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hey').click(function(){
        alert($('ul').css('height'));
           $(this).siblings('ul').css('height','10px');
        alert($('ul').css('height'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use by `line-height` CSS property,

### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vb472/1/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hey').click(function(){
        $('div').next().css('line-height','10px');
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="hey">Click me</div>
<ul>My Height</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    border:1px solid #FF0000;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

hope this would be help you!